# Different tabs with synchronized scroll

Tags: flutter

I have a widget for a tabbed layout named `Widget someWidget()`, contains 2 tabs which are `Widget tabA()` and `Widget tabB()`:

```
  Widget someWidget() {
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: (ScrollEndNotification notification) {
        //lazy load, fetching next data
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  if (selectedTab == "tabA") tabA()
                  else tabB(),


  Widget tabA() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 12,
        right: 12,
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("sometext"),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                child: Card(
                  child: DataTable(
                   //filling table


  Widget tabB() {
    // same layout with tabA but different content
```

Both tabs contain table. Let's say I open `someWidget` for the first time and by default, the one displayed is `tabA`. Then I scrolled the table until row 50, and switched to `tabB`. This is the first time I opened `tabB`, but the data displayed is already at row 50. If in `tabB` I scrolled till row 80, then switched to `tabA`, table in `tabA` would also displayed row 80, eventhough the last time I've only scrolled till row 50.

Why is it that when I scrolled in one tab, the other tab would also be scrolled? How to make so that when one tab is scrolled, the other tab's scroll won't be affected?

Comment: Which scrolling are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using same `SingleChildScrollView` for both widgets

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  if (selectedTab == "tabA") tabA()
                  else tabB(),
```

Remove it and add individually to your both widgets.

```
selectedTab == "tabA" ? SingleChildScrollView(child: Widget1()) : SingleChildScrollView(child: Widget2())
```